# How to distinguish between same controls in MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have 5 `CheckBox` and this is what they look like in the `View`:

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" Content="Cb1"/>
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" Content="Cb2"/>
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" Content="Cb3"/>
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" Content="Cb4"/>
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" Content="Cb5"/>
```

This is the some of the code that I have in my `ViewModel`:

```
class CheckBoxesViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
public CheckBoxesViewModel()
{
    CheckBoxes= new ObservableCollection<Models.CheckBoxes>();
    _canExecute = true;
}

private bool _IsSelected;
public bool IsSelected
{
    get
    {
        return _IsSelected;
    }
    set
    {
        _IsSelected = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
    }
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

private ObservableCollection<Models.CheckBoxes> _checkBoxes = new ObservableCollection<Models.CheckBoxes>();
public ObservableCollection<Models.CheckBoxes> CheckBoxes
{
    get { return _checkBoxes ; }
    set
    {
        _checkBoxes = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("CheckBoxes");
    }
}
}
```

The problem is that when I check/uncheck one of the checkboxes it affects all of them.

I assume that is because they have exact same binding, but I can not figure out how to make the code distinguish them.

I think I could use `Command` and `CommandParameters`, but that does not seem like the best solution.

P.S. Do let me know if you see something wrong with my code - I am still trying to learn the whole MVVM thing.

Comment: Well why do you have five checkboxes with the same binding? If you want to represent 5 different values, use 5 different properties...

Comment: @JonSkeet, but then wouldn't I have to write the same code 5 times? The `ÌsSelected` part that is

Comment: Yes, you would - although I'd personally collapse at least the getter into a single line. Fundamentally you've got 5 independent properties, right? Why would you *expect* to be able to represent them with a single property?

Comment: @JonSkeet, they have similar functions - checking a `CheckBox` shows another control that corresponds to the `CheckBox`, so I was trying to avoid typing too much code.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by that - but from the perspective of a the ViewModel, I'd expect them to mean different things. It's possible that you want to actually bind to a collection using a repeater instead, and expose *that* in the view model...

Comment: The first thing to make up your mind over is what steers these checkboxes, they just cannot have the same meaning.

Comment: @JonSkeet, each `CheckBox` has a corresponding `TextBox` that gets shown when it is checked. I was hoping to reuse the same code for all of the `CheckBox`es and only change some value that helps me distinguish them (e.g. `Content`)

Comment: But do you not see how having a *single* property doesn't let you differentiate between them at all? Ignore the UI side of things - just think in terms of the ViewModel. If I write `var vm = new CheckBoxesViewModel(); vm.IsSelected = true;` which of the 5 logical values would you expect that to be changing?

Comment: Lol, you're going through the codebehind to do this?  Nope of all nopes.  Add that info to your question, as an answer is inbound.

Comment: @JonSkeet, I do see that, however I was hoping I could use a `switch` statement or something by using some additional tag (or perhaps their name) to distinguish them. Anyway, the more I think about my 'idea' the less sense it is starting to make. Thanks everybody - I will not be deleting this question, so I will have something to cringe at in a couple of years.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement ICommand (google DelegateCommand to be able to treat an Action as ICommand) then you would bind the Command property of the CheckBox in the view to the Command on the view model.

ViewModel

```
public ICommand MyCommand { get; private set; }
.... MyCommand = new DelegateCommand((value) => this.DoStuff(value));
```

Xaml

```
<CheckBox Command={Binding MyCommand} Command Parameter={...} />
```

Answer (score 1):

From your stated purpose in comments (which really should have been in your question--this is a classic [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem))

You're attempting to route View logic through your ViewModel, which should be a hint that something's wrong here.  Your stated purpose is

> Each CheckBox has a corresponding TextBox that gets shown when it is checked. I was hoping to reuse the same code for all of the CheckBoxes and only change some value that helps me distinguish them (e.g. Content)

Toggling visibility is a View concern.  You can do it thusly

```
<StackPanel>
    <CheckBox x:Name = "cb1" />
    <!-- cb2 through cbn omitted -->
<StackPanel />
<StackPanel>
<StackPanel.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="btvc" />
</StackPanel.Resources>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding FirstTextBox}"
             Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, 
                                  ElementName=cb1, 
                                  Converter={StaticResource btvc}}" />
    <!-- SecondTextBox through NthTextBox omitted -->
</StackPanel />
```

I'm toggling visibility of the textbox by whether or not the corresponding checkbox was checked.

Now, if you're trying to munge together N textbox values into one property... You're making life too hard on yourself.

Comment: I understand your idea, but I would really like to create them programmatically rather than in the XAML

Comment: @AntonioPetrov Well, everybody is allowed to do things the hard way, costing them time and aggravation.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to 'programmatically add them", then you need to reverse your logic. Instead of 'adding controls' to the form, you need to think of 'adding data' to your ViewModel. This is how you stay within MVVM guidelines, as your tag suggests.

Here's how you can reverse the logic....The ItemsControl has the ability to bind to a collection of ViewModels. This control also 'automagically' determines what control to use for each item in the collection by using DataTemplates.

Here's the XAML code:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding myCollection}" >
    <ItemsControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:myViewModelForItemA}">
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" Content="{Binding aName}"></CheckBox>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:myViewModelForItemB}">
            <RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" Content="{Binding aName}"></RadioButton>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Resources>
</ItemsControl>
```

As you can probably see, the Binding "myCollection" is the collection you add your ViewModel Instances to (this is an ObservableCollection).

Each DataTemplate in the IntemsControl.Resources is how you want each item to look (you can even place multiple controls inside each DataTemplate, just remember that whatever you bind these to will bind to the ViewModel in the collection (i.e. myViewModelForItemA, myViewModelForItemB).

The code in your main view model:

```
public ObservableCollection<object> myCollection { set; get; } 

....

myCollection = new ObservableCollection<object>();
myViewModelForItemA anItem = new myViewModelForItemA();
myCollection.Add(anItem);
//now anItem of type (myViewModelForItemA) is in our collection
//and the ItemsControl automagically added a CheckBox to it's collection
//and bound isChecked to anItem.isChecked property, and bound
//the Content to anItem.aName property.
```